# Escaping single quotes in view (kendo grid)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a view with a Kendo grid in it.

In the piece of code that follows, my '#=Name' contains a string. This string sometimes has a single quote in it. As you can probably guess, this single quote is killing my onclick call.

Any suggestions on how to handle the single quote?

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ActiveAssetCount).ClientTemplate("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"EntityPage.OpenWindow('#=EntityID#','#=Name.trim()#','true');\" name=\"ActiveAssetCount\" # if (ActiveAssetCount <= 0) { # style=\"display: none;\" # } else { # id=\"#=EntityID#\" class=\"AssetButton\" value=\"#= ActiveAssetCount # Assets\" # } # />").Width(120).Title("A. Assets").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "AssetColumn" });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could encode it as an html entity on in the datasource. Use `&apos;`, or a prime mark (decent source for html entities: http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=punct)

**Edit**: Changed `&lsquo;` to `&apos;` per comment by @Misi.

Comment: For me it didn't work &lsquo;. &apos; is valid in HTML5, but not HTML4.